# A Sobolev embedding question

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Is there a condition on $s$ for which it is true that the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R})\subset L^1(\mathbb{R})$ continuously? Note that $s\in\mathbb{R}$ here, possibly negative.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about embeddings for fractional Sobolev spaces?